# Cannot see 'sent' packets on wireshark despite specifying correct interface

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I am using scapy because I have a testing scenario where a single TCP packet with a specific payload size has to be sent. Using the python socket module and sending over TCP breaks the packet into several smaller packets.

I have looked at similar answers for this issue and have addressed two common causes of the problem.

- I have no firewall active
- I have confirmed the conf.route and specified the correct interface (code below)

The target device is running on a subnet connected through a USB 3.0 to Gig Ethernet adapter.

```
In [17]: from scapy.arch.windows import *

In [18]: from scapy.all import *

In [19]: conf.route.route('192.168.0.250')
Out[19]:
('\\Device\\NPF_{E2E3F879-C0EF-4044-8948-6C156428AAD4}',
 '192.168.0.200',
 '0.0.0.0')

In [20]: get_if_list()
Out[20]:
['{DF475EB4-4CF9-4325-8881-9DFF27673300}',
 '{D03BA4BA-2CA7-40AE-AA23-9A0717B1BBB4}',
 '{D80B8705-1B52-4EE7-9D37-3C37FF589BDC}',
 '{A084D1BE-7FDF-44F0-80E6-385302833BDE}',
 '{E2E3F879-C0EF-4044-8948-6C156428AAD4}',
 '{4962146B-E32E-4A2E-8630-EA1335AB84DE}',
 '{A050E9CA-13D6-44F7-A4D1-7C1E07B6C20C}',
 '{FF7DA542-4F6B-4278-A042-544C648342FE}',
 '\\Device\\NPF_Loopback']

In [21]: for itf in get_windows_if_list():
    ...:     if itf['guid'] == conf.route.route('192.168.0.250')[0].split('_',1)[1]:
    ...:         print(itf['name'])
    ...:
Ethernet 2

In [22]: from string import ascii_lowercase

In [23]: from random import choices

In [24]: data = ''.join(choices(ascii_lowercase, k=4096))

In [25]: mac = getmacbyip('192.168.0.250')

In [26]: mac
Out[26]: '00:0d:8d:02:a6:e9'

In [27]: pkt = IP(dst='192.168.0.250') / TCP(dport=5000) / Ether(dst=mac) / data

In [28]: send(pkt, iface='Ethernet 2')
.
Sent 1 packets.
```

When I open the wireshark capture on the same interface 'Ethernet 2', there is no captured data with a target of the same IP and TCP port number I specified in the code. Also, the targeted device shows no sign of receiving the message.

Comment: A particular python client can reproduce the "outbound packets are not visible" symptom, good. Can another client, like tcpdump, reproduce that symptom?

Comment: @J_H Ran tcpdump with filter for 'host 192.168.0.250'. Can see ARP requests and IP traffic for port 137 but not the sent packets. I think this is an MTU issue as the code and capture will work if I decrease the value of k (for example 1024) when creating my data.